# Conditional date formatting based on adjacent cells

Tags: excel, date, conditional-statements, highlight

```
| start date | end date | 
| 1/19/2019  | 2/1/2019 |
| 5/1/2019   | 3/8/2019 | 
| 4/1/2019   | 9/1/2019 |
```

I have a list of date in excel with A1 being the start date and B1 being the end date. I need to highlight the cells in A that end after than their adjacent cells in B, since start date can't be after end date. I tried "Use a formula to determine which cells to format" and did =a2>b2 and then apply it to =$A:$A and =A:A, but neither seems to be highlighting like I need. Any recommendations on how to do highlight the A cells only that are larger than the adjacent B?

Comment: When applied to `A:A` the formula should start on row 1: `=A1>B1`

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your formula and "Applies to" range line up, i.e. if the formula is `A2` then the "Applies to" range should start in A2.

[image]

If you are applying the conditional formatting to the entire column, without highlighting the title row, you could do the following:

```
 =AND(ISNUMBER(A1),A1>B1)
```

[image]

Comment: So I want it to apply to the entire column. The issue is, when I do =A1>B1, it also highlights the title (1) row. But I figured it out - I just put in a new rule to apply first that makes the first row no format.

Answer (score 0):

Key here is first select cell A1 then select the whole column A and then click Home | Conditional formatting | new rule | Use a formula...

In the text box format values... write this
   =A1>B1

Click the format button and set the custom formatting

Click ok

Edit: as OP stated in the comments not in the question, you should select first A2